# How can I modify this code to enable users to add multiple items(number of items=n) in the bill?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The code is a follows:

```
n=str(input("Enter the name of the item:"))
p=int(input("Enter the price of the item:"))
r=int(input("Enter the quantity of the item:"))
tot=p*r
GST=tot+(5/100)*tot
print("Bill:")
print("Item", "\t\t\tPrice", "\tQuantity", "\tGST", "\tTotal cost")
print(n,"\t\t", p, "\t", r, "\t\t5%","\t", GST)
```

The number of items n must be given as user input

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Comment: Try to wrap the code inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting 'v 'variable' to list so u can access it using indexes and even user can enter many items to it

Answer (score 0):

why don't you make a loop like:

```py
stopped = False
items = []
prices = []
quantities = []
while not stopped:
  items.append(str(input("Enter the name of the item:")))
  prices.append(int(input("Enter the price of the item:")))
  quantities.append(int(input("Enter the quantity of the item:")))
  c = ""
  while c not in ["yes", "no"]:
      c = input("continue ? type yes or no")
  if c == "no":
    stopped = True

# then make your processing of these lists.
```